# Error while installing cordova by using npm install -g cordova.Can anyone help me to solve this?

Tags: cordova, npm

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\n
ode_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\node
js\node_modules\.staging']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
```

Please try run this command again as `root/Administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

Error says it all. Run your `cli` as administrator.

Right click on Command Prompt > Run as administrator and run your command again.

**Adding cordova.js**

`cordova.js` will be available on real device or emulator. Just add it to your `index.html` and it will be called.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: tried this then appears a warning "npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.245
.222.162:80"

Comment: What version `npm` you have? You can get `npm` cersion with command `npm -v`. Try updating to latest `npm install npm -g`. It's known issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9204 but should give better explaining if `npm` is `>3.5`.

Comment: i am using npm 3.3.12

Comment: Okay. Then run `npm install npm -g` as administrator. And try again your original command.

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g cordovo
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Guest Account\
ppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cord
o"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.0
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/cordov
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'cordovo' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself

Comment: It's `npm install -g cordova` not `npm install -g cordovo`. Notice the a instead of o in the end.

Comment: ok thank you..How will we get the cordova.jar and cordova.js .Did you have any idea about dat

Comment: I edited my answer. You don't need `cordova.jar`. Why you think you need it?